# Move Window Linux C

Tags: c++, linux, window

i'd like to make a function that can move a window in Linux in C++ by its PID. So I've tryed in under Windows. But I have trouble to compile it for Linux.
Is there any mean to do it with Qt ? Since I haven't found one, I've tryed to compile for Linux.

I'm using the MoveWindow function, which is part of the Windows API. Is there any Linux equivalent ?

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to do that by hand if you don't really want to as there already are lots of tools out there, that can perform such tasks as moving, resizing, maximizing and whatever windows.

One tool you might want to take a closer look upon goes by the name of `wmctrl` even if you don't intend to use maybe you'll find some interesting tricks by taking a look into the sources.

The task of moving a window only known by the pid of the client that created the window might not be the easiest tasks of all for a couple of reasons.

- First of all you really shouldn't try to do this as in the X Windows philosophy it is the job of the window manager to arrange the windows on the screen.

  As well ICCCM (see: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-Client_Communication_Conventions_Manual) as the EWM spec (see: http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) strongly discourage any client from trying to move resize or whatever on its own. Most probably moving windows "owned" by another client might be considered even bigger evil.
- The second problem you might face is, that the X 11 protocol doesn't have any notion of pid.

  As it was designed to be used over a network you never can't be really sure the program runs on the same machine as the one you are currently sitting in front of. As such there isn't much sense in something like a pid as by chance there might be any number of clients with identical pids displaying windows on the same X Server if they ran on different machines.

Fortunately enough it is not all that bad, as the EWMH spec encourages any client to set the **_NET_WM_PID** property on its top level window the the pid of the client that created the window.

Again adhering to the EWMH spec isn't enforced by the X Server in any way so that while practically propably almost all clients will set it there's still no guarantee you'll find the window belonging to a specific pid.

### Possibilities

While the whole points mentioned until here might seem rather limiting in fact most probably rather the opposite is true. Even because practically it is relatively easy to totally mess up any other client running in an X session the whole set of rules about how to be a good citizen in the X word were introduced.

As the X11 protocol itself is a network protocol (well not 100% true as locally running clients most probably will be communicating with the X Server via a UNIX domain socket) there isn't any specific library required to talk to the X Server.

Talking about C as mentioned in your question the **Xlib** has long been the one and only one implementation in wide use but there's also another binding called **xcb**. With a slightly changed API in comparison to the Xlib.

### Xlib

Speaking Xlib I've never ever used any xcb until now, so I can't tell you too much about it might be the following methods that  might be of use.

- **XOpenDisplay** - open connection to the X server
- **XQueryTree**   - aquire the tree of windows currently alive on the server
- **XInternAtom**  - no fear it isn't dangerous. Just read about it in the manuals as you'll need it the get the "atom" mapping to _NET_WM_PID mentioned above
- **XListProperties** - search for the _NET_WM_PID property with the value you are looking for
- **XConfigureWindow**, **XMoveWindow**, **XResizeWindow**, ... - to finally perform whatever you wish to do.

All functions mentioned above should be documented in the manual pages. Just use `man XOpenDisplay` for example.

Oh, and be sure to learn about all the other tools at your disposal to further investigate about the X Window world. Run `xlsatoms`, check what `xwininfo` reports an take a list at the output of `xprop` for one single (!) window alone. Try to set some yourself to see what happens `xprop` will even do that for you if you ask politely.

Comment: tldr: X window system sucks

Comment: Example: I'm making desktop app, on a debug build I want the UI window always moved in a certain position on startup. And console output window of the same app to be moved right below it. The fact I can't do this on linux reliably with something similar to a single `MoveWindow` call is absolutely and utterly idiotic.

Comment: Might depend on the point of view. IMHO it should be _my_ choice as a user where which window pops up and not the decision of the develepor hardcoding his or her view of just the "right" spot to place it. X philosophy in this particular case means no more or less than: Common just let the user decide himself, would you?. Almost any WindowManager I know of gives the user an opportunity to explicitly specify where which window should pop up and at what size. So at least for me having some Tool just ignoring any of my choices would be the real nuisance.

Comment: exactly, user should ALWAYS be able to position windows wherever he wants - either manually (using keyboard or mouse) or programmatically - by calling the OS API MoveWindow call. X window system does not have a reliable way to do this - as it's FUBARed beyond repair. Hopefully Wayland (or whoever is going to replace X) won't have the same problems.

Comment: In other words - consistent, direct CONTROL of where to put windows is taken away from the user. And given to Stupid-Piece-Of-Software - AKA - the window manager. And the only choice a USER has is 1) write his own window manager or 2) use X11 without a window manager. What a wonderful world to be in!

Comment: @mikyra Sometimes the user wants or needs the program to automatically pop up on a certain monitor or in a certain position. It's better to have the freedom to do that, and be able to fulfill such requirements.